# ant build error after exporting with eclipse

Tags: android, ant

I exported my project to build.xml in order to use ant.

When I execute 'ant debug' from the command line it outputs Target "debug" does not exist in the project.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to build with the auto generated ant scripts from android. You need to do an `android update project` on the project in question and then use the `build.xml` file that is generated from that.

To do this:

1. Go to the project in question with a terminal or command prompt.
2. Then type the following command `android update project -p .` This will update the current project that you are inside.

*The command above also assumes you have the `android.bat` location on your path. If you do not, you need to use the entire path to your `android.bat` location. Which should be similar to `android-sdk/tools/android.bat`.*

Comment: No problem. If you have any troubles doing this, please let us know.